# OpenCV SURF descriptor matching

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

This is the function for comparing SURF descriptors which I found in **find_obj.cpp** of OpenCV samples. I am basically not able to understand how is this calculating Euclidean distance between the descriptors.

Is is calculating for every i-th descriptor or whole image at once?

I know this is a basic question but I really appreciate you response.
Thanks.

```
double
compareSURFDescriptors( const float* d1, const float* d2, double best, int length )
{
    double total_cost = 0;
    assert( length % 4 == 0 );
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i += 4 )
    {
        double t0 = d1[i  ] - d2[i  ];
        double t1 = d1[i+1] - d2[i+1];
        double t2 = d1[i+2] - d2[i+2];
        double t3 = d1[i+3] - d2[i+3];
        total_cost += t0*t0 + t1*t1 + t2*t2 + t3*t3;
        if( total_cost > best )
            break;
    }
    return total_cost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For every i-th descriptor in Image 1 to the every j-th descriptor from the Image 2.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation mainly based on literature [(Bay et al. 2004)](http://nichol.as/papers/Bay/Surf:%20Speeded%20up%20robust%20features.pdf).

Let's say we have an image with the keypoints detected. In order for a descriptor to be calculated for a keypoint, a square region is defined around it (according to the paper a window of size `20s` is used, where `s` is the scale at which the keypoint was detected). This region is then divided in 4X4=16 square subregions (see image). For each of these sub-regions the descriptor 4 values are calculated resulting in a 4-dim vector `vi=[a1i,a2i,a3i,a4i]` for `i=[1:16]`  (see the paper or [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) to understand what those values are). Hence, the final vector of the descriptor accumulates the values of these 16 4-dim vectors one after the other. Hence, the descriptor results in a with 16*4=64-dim vector.

To sum up: each keypoint is described by a 64-vector. Every 4 values in this vector describe one of the 16 sub-regions in the neighbourhood of the keypoint. (this can also be 128 for the extended version SURF-128)

[image]

So, if you see at the overall c++ code, the input of this function is just one descriptor (one keypoint) from the object (d1) and one descriptor from the image(d2). Basically, the comparison is conducted between 2 64-dim vectors (or 128 in case of the extended version). The assertion that the length of the vector should be a multiple of 4, verifies that these descriptors are formed by 4-dim vectors appended one after the other.

In order to identify if a keypoint of the object is similar with a keypoint of the image you compare the same sub-regions around them. For this reason every 4 values are compared together (their difference/distance is calculated) and the total cost is increased (based on how dissimilar they are). If the total cost becomes bigger than a threshold value (best) then there is no reason to continue the comparison, the points are not similar!

I hope this helps and I did not confuse you even more!